# Invalid Podfile for iOS GCM Example

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am trying to install the GCM Example Xcode project, following the instructions on the Google developers page
    https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start

but failing at step 1 with this message:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..
```

The full transcript goes like this:

```
$ pod try Google --no-repo-update

Trying Google
1: Samples/admob/AdMobExample.xcodeproj
2: Samples/analytics/AnalyticsExample.xcodeproj
3: Samples/appinvites/AppInvitesExample.xcodeproj
4: Samples/gcm/GcmExample.xcodeproj
5: Samples/signin/SignInExample.xcodeproj
Which project would you like to open
4
Performing CocoaPods Installation

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..

 #  from /private/var/folders/d5/f4qpz1r530xbw5cyrbfk094h0000gp/T/CocoaPods/Try/Google/Samples/gcm/Podfile:10
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # and delete the link_with command.
 >  link_with 'GcmExample', 'GcmExampleSwift'
 #  ------------------------------------------
```

I have tried modifying the podfile as suggested in the error message, but the Podfile is regenerated, even when run with the `--no-repo-update option` and produces the same error.

I have no prior experience with Pods so any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the path: "/private/var/folders/lx/78jh00l90p95cs1cy_545t2r0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/Google/Samples/gcm" then just open the pod file and update it as

```
# GcmExample
 target 'GcmExample' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
   pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
end
# If using CocoaPods 1.0.0+, use the new target syntax.
#target 'GcmExample'
#target 'GcmExampleSwift'

# and delete the link_with command.
#link_with 'GcmExample', 'GcmExampleSwift'
```

Then, pod install

Comment: Thanks Mahesh.  In addition to your suggestion, I uncommented the 'target' lines in the podfile (edited in your answer), and then installed successfully.